# R3 Corda IOUs: Why 'http://localhost:10013/api/example/ious' is giving empty response even though I created IOUs using web interface

Tags: corda

I recently strated exploring Corda. I have installed Corda and sample CorDapp (cordapp_example) on my location machine and ran the nodes and tried to access ious of one of the nodes (Lets say PartyA), by using below URL, it just showing empty []. I also noticed error:

> netty.AMQPClient.operationComplete - Failed to connect to 20.198.218.65:10011 {}

Note that this IP address is not my local address.

http://localhost:10013/api/example/ious

Comment: Have you created an IOU yet? `[]` is the standard output until an IOU has actually been issued onto the ledger. I think `10013` corresponds to `PartyC`'s webserver, so you'd have to create an IOU involving them first.

Answer (score 0):

`[]` is the standard output until an IOU has actually been issued onto the ledger. I think port `10013` corresponds to `PartyC`'s webserver, so you'd have to create an IOU involving `PartyC` first.